# Solving underdetermined Lyapunov equations?

Tags: numerics, linear-algebra

I'm wondering if there's an efficient way to get a solution (ie, [`LeastSquares`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LeastSquares.html)solution)  for Lyapunov equation $AX+XA=C$ with symmetric positive definite $ A $ and $ C $.

I want something that would work like [`LyapunovSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LyapunovSolve.html), but would work for underconstrained problems, i.e., `LyapunovSolve[A, A]` should give me something whose spectrum looks like $ I $.

I tried a naive approach which is to do Kronecker expansion followed by `LeastSquares`, which gives the desired result

```
kronExpand[x_] := Module[{ii},
   ii = IdentityMatrix[First[Dimensions[x]]];
   ii\[TensorProduct]x + Transpose[x]\[TensorProduct]ii
   ];
lyapLeastSquares[A_, B_] := Module[{d, X},
  X = LeastSquares[kronExpand[A], vec[B]];
  X = unvec[X, d];
```

(check [this notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/lyapunov.nb) for an end-to-end example)

However, this expansion is too large to be practical. IE, my matrices are on the order of 1000 which is fast using `LyapunovSolve`, but doing Kronecker expansion means that I have matrices on the order of 1M-by-1M. Any suggestions on how to make this feasible?

Comment: Are you trying to solve AX+XA=A?

Comment: Trying to solve AX+XA=C where C is allowed to be A (but can also be other values)

Comment: It seems in principle one could borrow the logic from Matlab Lyapunov solver and skip all divisions by zero (which result from system being underdetermined) -- https://github.com/msubhransu/matrix-sqrt/blob/master/lyap2.m

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up with two versions below by reverse engineering Matlab implementation. They both seem to give me the same answer as the least squares solution when A, B are positive semi-positive (experiments [notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/lyapunov.nb))

```
lyapSvd[A_, B_] := Module[{U, s, C, cutoff, sdiv, Y},
   {U, S, V} = SingularValueDecomposition[A];
   s = Diagonal[S];
   C = U\[Transpose].B.V;
   smat = Outer[Plus, s, s];
   sinv = Map[If[# > 0, 1/#, #] &, smat, {2}];
   Y = C*sinv;
   X = U.Y.Transpose[V];
   Print["errorSvd=", Norm[X.A + A.X - B]];
   X
   ];

lyapSpectral[A_, B_] := Module[{U, s, C, cutoff, sdiv, Y},
   U = Transpose@Eigenvectors[A];
   s = Eigenvalues[A];
   C = U\[Transpose].B.U;
   cutoff = Max[s]*$MachineEpsilon;
   sdiv = Map[If[# > cutoff, 1/#, #] &, Outer[Plus, s, s], {2}];
   Y = C*sdiv;
   X = U.Y.Transpose[U];
   Print["errorSpectral=", Norm[A.X + X.A - B]];
   X
   ];
```

Comment: You might want to include the definition of `erank` for completeness.

Comment: Oh that's just the trace divide by norm, was left over from experiments, fixed