# Solving "Lyapunov-like" equation AX+X'B=C

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

Is there some way I can solve the following equation with $d-by-d$ matrices in Mathematica in reasonable time?

$$AX+X'B=C$$

My solution below calls linsolve on $d^2,d^2$ matrix, which is too expensive for my case (my d is 1000)

```
kmat[n_] := Module[{mat1, mat2},
   mat1 = Array[{#1, #2} &, {n, n}];
   mat2 = Transpose[mat1];
   pos[{row_, col_}] := row + (col - 1)*n;
   poses = Flatten[MapIndexed[{pos[#1], pos[#2]} &, mat2, {2}], 1];
   Normal[SparseArray[# -> 1 & /@ poses]]
   ];
unvec[Wf_, rows_] := Transpose[Flatten /@ Partition[Wf, rows]];
vec[x_] := Flatten[Transpose[x]];

solveLyapunov2[a_, b_, c_] := Module[{},
  dims = Length[a];
  ii = IdentityMatrix[dims];
  x0 = LinearSolve[
    KroneckerProduct[ii, a] + 
     KroneckerProduct[Transpose[b], ii].kmat[dims], vec[c]];
  X = unvec[x0, dims];
  Print["error is ", Norm[a.X + Transpose[X].b - c]];
  X
  ]

a = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {3, 3}];
b = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {3, 3}];
c = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {3, 3}];
X = solveLyapunov2[a, b, c]
```

*Edit Sep 30*: An approximate solution would be useful as well. In my application $C$ is the gradient, and $X$ is the preconditioned gradient, so I'm looking for something that's much better than a "default" solution of $X_0=C$

Comment: Have a look at this paper Consistency and efficient solution of the Sylvester equation for ⋆-congruence. Electronic J. of Linear Algebra, 22:849–863, 2011. https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/96c8/d0708c34cc7af2c9463784454f9a19ae4bac.pdf The large-scale solution of this equation is still an open problem.

Comment: Have a look at the new solution

Comment: This is amazing, thank you! My matrices are actually singular, so I had to modify Lyapunov solver for that (https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/206160/solving-underdetermined-lyapunov-equations), I could probably adapt your solution for that case as well (ie, use pseudo-inverses instead of inverses)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some mathematics I found a (pair of) method that can utilize `LyapunovSolve`.

```
g = a + b\[Transpose];
ig = Inverse[g];
Print["Cond Num = ", Norm[g] Norm[ig]];
h = (c + c\[Transpose])/2;
u = LyapunovSolve[a.ig, -ig\[Transpose].b, 
   c - a.ig.h - h.ig\[Transpose].b];
u = (u - u\[Transpose])/2; (* Re-symmetrize, secrect ingredient *)
x = ig.(h + u);
Norm[a.x + Transpose[x].b - c]  (* verify *)
```

Or:

```
d = a - b\[Transpose];
id = Inverse[d];
Print["Cond Num = ", Norm[d] Norm[id]];
q = (c - c\[Transpose])/2;
v = LyapunovSolve[a.id, id\[Transpose].b, 
   c - a.id.q + q.id\[Transpose].b];
v = (v + v\[Transpose])/2; (* Re-symmetrize, secrect ingredient *)
x = id.(q + v);
Norm[a.x + Transpose[x].b - c]  (* verify *)
```

Just pick whatever one that has lower conditional number.

### Mathematics behind

From
$$
  a x + x^T b = c
$$
we get
$$
  (a+b^T) x + x^T (b+a^T) = c + c^T.
$$
Rewrite as ($g = a + b^T$, $2h = c + c^T$)
$$
  g x + (g x)^T = 2h.
$$

Define $y$ and $u$ by
$$
  y = g x = h + u,
$$
where $h = h^T$, $u = -u^T$. We can solve $h$ by the $g$ equation above. Then substitute $x=g^{-1} (h + u)$ to the original equation to solve $u$ (the (anti)symmetric $h$ and $u$ are the keys to eliminate the "transpose"): 
$$
  a g^{-1} u - u (g^{-1})^T b = c - a g^{-1} h - h (g^{-1})^T b.
$$
After solving $u$ you can get $x$.

Similar steps for the other code.

**Edit:** Add error statistics.

[image: Error of the algorithm]

The error (`Norm[a.x + Transpose[x].b - c]`) for different size random matrices $a,b,c$. The blue line uses the algorithm here, red line uses the method in yarchik's answer. Somehow the method here is more accurate.

---

(Useless old answer that is not targeting the question)

Try the built-in function [LyapunovSolve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LyapunovSolve.html).

e.g.

```
n = 1000;
a = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {n, n}];
b = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {n, n}];
c = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, {n, n}];

Timing[x = LyapunovSolve[a, b, c];]
(* Out: {10.964, Null} *)

Norm[a.x + x.b - c]
(* Out: 4.98744*10^-8 *)
```

For computation of well-solved mathematical problems, always search built-in function first.

Comment: It's missing a transpose, I need `a.x + Transpose[x].b - c` to be 0

Comment: Aha, my fault. Let me see if I can fix it.

Comment: thanks, nice trick

Comment: btw, could you send your email to me at yaroslavvb@gmail.com? I wanted to credit you in the write-up for this reduction

Comment: email sent [;-)

Answer (score 7):

### General matrices

For the desired matrix sizes I have doubts that a numerical solution would be feasible. Here is a simplified code using sparse matrices.

```
tmSylvester[n_]:=Module[{a,b,c,sA,sB,sC,sAB},
a=RandomReal[{-3,3},{n,n}];
b=RandomReal[{-3,3},{n,n}];
c=RandomReal[{-3,3},{n,n}];
sA=SparseArray[Table[{(i-1)n+l,(k-1)n+l}->a[[i,k]],{i,n},{k,n},{l,n}]//Flatten];
sB=SparseArray[Table[{(l-1)n+j,(k-1)n+l}->b[[k,j]],{k,n},{j,n},{l,n}]//Flatten];
sAB=sA+sB;
sC=SparseArray[Table[{(i-1)n+j}->c[[i,j]],{i,n},{j,n}]//Flatten];
First[Timing[LinearSolve[sAB,sC];]]]
```

Now, let us plot the timing

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{n,tmSylvester[n]},{n,10,120,10}],Joined->True,PlotTheme->{"Frame","Monochrome"}, FrameLabel->{"Matrix Size","Time(s)"}]
```

[image]

Even at a very optimistic extrapolation it is unlikely that the `n=1000` calculation would be routinely possible. There are, however, experts here that might be able to further tune up the linear solver.

### Nonsingular matrices

According to F. M. Dopico, J. González, D. Kressner, and V. Simoncini. *Projection methods for large-scale T-Sylvester equations*, in Mathematics of Computation (2015), under the usual conditions of existence the following equations have equal unique solutions

$$B^{−T} A X − X A^{−T} B = B^{−T} C − B^{−T} C^{T} A^{−T} B;$$
$$AX + X^T B = C, $$
where $A^{-T}\equiv(A^{-1})^T$.

Therefore, we can use the Lyapunov solver

```
tmDopico[n_]:=Module[{a,b,c},
a=RandomReal[{-3,3},{n,n}];
b=RandomReal[{-3,3},{n,n}];
c=RandomReal[{-3,3},{n,n}];
First[Timing[LyapunovSolve[Transpose[Inverse[b]].a,-Transpose[Inverse[a]].b,Transpose[Inverse[b]].c-Transpose[Inverse[b]].Transpose[c].Transpose[Inverse[a]].b];]]]
```

Let us check the timing:

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{n,tmDopico[n]},{n,50,1000,50}],Joined->True,PlotTheme->{"Frame","Monochrome"}, FrameLabel->{"Matrix size","Time(s)"}]
```

[image]

The method should therefore have $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ scaling under favorite conditions.