# How to solve for Transpose[X] A X = B

Tags: linear-algebra, coordinate-transformation

I need to find a transformation matrix of the metric tensor but I don't know how to solve for X from

```
Transpose[X]*A*X=B
```

Comment: Try DiscreteRiccatiSolve

Comment: Just noting that `*` does not denote matrix multiplication in Mathematica. `.` does.

Comment: @bills How would you use `DiscreteRiccatiSolve` to solve for `X`? I'm not familiar with control-systems lingo, but it doesn't seem possible. There's no $x^\dagger$ in the Riccati equation. The closest thing is $(r+b^\dagger.x.b)^{-1}$.

Comment: Please post a specific example with the explicit `A` and `B` matrices.

Comment: There may not be a general solution unless `A` and `B` satisfy some further conditions.

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/207040/solving-lyapunov-like-equation-axxb-c/207105#207105) some similar equations are solved

Comment: I think @MichaelE2 is right. It must be [`RiccatiSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiccatiSolve.html) instead of [`DiscreteRiccatiSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteRiccatiSolve.html).

Answer (score 3):

It may be possible using [`RiccatiSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiccatiSolve.html) which can solve an equation of the form

$$a^{T }.x+x.a-x.b.r^{-1}.b^{T }.x+q=0$$

If we assume $x=x^T$ and then choose values $a=0$, $b=I$, $r=A^{-1}$, and $q=B$, the above equation becomes

$$0^{T }.x+x.0-x^T.I.(A^{-1})^{-1}.I^{T }.x+B=0$$

$$ x^T.A.x=B$$

The assumption $x=x^T$ specifies conditions that the matrices $A$ and $B$ must satisfy. You can see them in the details section of [`RiccatiSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RiccatiSolve.html).

Here is a small concocted example.

```
q = IdentityMatrix[2];
r = {{5, 1}, {1, 5}};
x = RiccatiSolve[{ConstantArray[0, {2, 2}], IdentityMatrix[2]}, {q, r}]
```

> {{1/2 (2 + Sqrt[6]), 1/2 (-2 + Sqrt[6])}, {1/2 (-2 + Sqrt[6]), 
>     1/2 (2 + Sqrt[6])}}

```
With[{A = Inverse[r], B = q}, Transpose[x].A.x - B] // Simplify
```

> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}